# Prove that if $R$ is a relation on $A$, then $R$ has a reflexive closure.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$. Then $R$ has a reflexive closure.

My attempt:

Let

$$i_A = \{(a,a) \mid a \in A\}$$

which means $i_A \in A \times A$

Consider set $R \cup i_A $.

To prove that $R \cup i_A $ is a reflexive closure, we need to show that

1. $R \subseteq R \cup i_A $
2. $R \cup i_A$ is reflexive.
3. For every relation $T \subseteq A \times A$, if $R \subseteq T$ and $T$ is reflexive, then $S \subseteq T$.

---

1.

By definition of $\cup$, we know that for all $x$, $x \in R \implies R \cup i_A$, hence $R \subseteq R \cup i_A $

2.

Take $a \in A$. Since $(a,a) \in i_A$ it follows that $(a,a) \in R \cup i_A$

3.

Suppose $T \subseteq A \times A$, $R \subseteq T$ and $T$ is reflexive.

Since $T$ is reflexive, we have $i_A \subseteq T$; we also know that $R \subseteq T$, which implies that $R \cup i_A \subseteq T$

We've shown that three properties hold, hence $R \cup i_A$ is a reflexive closure of $R$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Looks fine at a glance.  You seem to be missing an "$x\in$" in line one and I'm not really sure how necessary some of those words are.  You should tailor your wordings and proofs to your audience but for other students and a teacher at a point in a course that you are talking about relations it should already be a well established fact that $E\subseteq E\cup F$ that needs no additional explanation.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I agree that first part looks verbose (and perhaps redundant). How should I reword it?

Comment: The big part of the work was in defining $i_A$.  From there I would have said "it is clear that..."